# Jquery change .click function to automatic change

Tags: jquery, onclick, gallery

I'm using the following code below to show a large full screen slider. What I'm attempting to do is substitute the .click function with a timed event so each image changes after a period of time (say 7 seconds) rather than when the links are clicked.

Been working on this for half a day and I'm still stuck so any help you can provide would be greatly greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Dave

```
    jQuery(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.panorama .panorama-view').panorama360();
if ($('.panorama #thumbnails .thumbers a').length > 1) { // check if there are multiple panoramas
    $('.panorama .panorama_controls a').click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $active = $('.panorama #thumbnails .thumbers a.active');
        if ($(this).hasClass('panorama_next')) {
            if ($active.length == 0) $active = $('.panorama #thumbnails .thumbers a:last');
            $next = $active.parent().next('li');
            console.log($next);
            if ($next.length > 0) { // check to see if it's not the first thumb
                $('a:first',$next).trigger('click');
            } else { // load last panorama in the thumb stack
                $('.panorama #thumbnails .thumbers:first a').trigger('click');
            }
        }
        else {
            if ($active.length == 0) $active = $('.panorama #thumbnails a:first');
            $prev = $active.parent().prev('li');
            if ($prev.length > 0) { // check to see if it's not the first thumb
                $('a:first',$prev).trigger('click');
            } else { // load last panorama in the thumb stack
                $('.panorama #thumbnails .thumbers:last a').trigger('click');
            }
        }
    });
} else { // you can hide the controls because there is only one panorama loaded
    $('.panorama .panorama_controls').hide();
}
$('.panorama #thumbnails .thumbers a').click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) return;

    $('.panorama .preloader').show();
    $('#thumbnails .thumbers a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.panorama .panorama-view').hide();
    $('.panorama .panorama-container').html($(this).next().html());
    $('.panorama .panorama-view').panorama360({ sliding_direction: 0 });
    $('h1.main-header').html($(this).data("title"));
    $('.main-desc').html($(this).data("description"));

});
$('.panorama .hotspot').fancybox({

        padding     : 0,
        fitToView   : true,
        mouseWheel  : false,
        maxWidth: '600',
        minHeight: '400',

        autoCenter: true,

        closeClick  : false
});

var pictures = [],

    $thumbnails = $( '#thumbnails' );

    // jScrollPane

$thumbnails.find( 'ul' ).width( function() {
    var totalWidth = 0;
    $( this ).find( 'li' ).each( function() {
        totalWidth += $( this ).outerWidth( true );
    });
    return totalWidth;
});

$thumbnails.jScrollPane();

var jScrollPaneApi = $thumbnails.data( 'jsp' );

$( window ).bind( 'resize', function() {
    jScrollPaneApi.reinitialise();
});

    }); // END doc ready
    }); // END function
```

Comment: Your jQuery selectors could use some refinement. `$('.panorama #thumbnails .thumbers a')`, why not just give your `<a>` a class?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than replace it, why not just trigger the click function?

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.panorama .panorama_controls a.panorama_next').click();
}, 7000);
```

Comment: Hi derek, thanks for the reply. Where would I place this function or would it replace something else?

Comment: @DaveHassall, just tack it on to the end of your document ready function.  No need to replace anything.  All that statement does it tells the browser to click the link every 7 seconds. You then don't have to alter any of the original code.